# discord py stop playing (voice)

Tags: python, discord.py

im making a discord bot with discord py but i have a problem:
My problem is that when our dear member hits the $stop command, the sound should not continue * the bot should not die, only the sound should stop
my code:

```
@app.command()
async def stop(ctx):
    voice = discord.utils.get(app.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice == None:
        await ctx.send(f"hey {ctx.author.mention} first bot need to join a voice channel!")
    elif (ctx.author.voice) == None:
        await ctx.send(f"hey {ctx.author.mention} first you need join to a voice channel!")
    else:
        # voice_1 = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        await voice.stop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `disconnect()` function:

```py
async def stop(ctx):
    # ...
    else:
        # ...
        await voice.disconnect()
```

This will disconnect the bot from the voice channel.

Comment: * the bot should not die, only the sound should stop

Answer (score 0):

For some reason you need to check if the bot is in voice channel or, then you can disconnect it

````
    async def _leave(self, ctx:commands.Context):
        voiceChannel = ctx.voice_client
        if not voiceChannel:
            await ctx.send("Bot not in any voice channel")
        
        await voiceChannel.disconnect()
        await ctx.send(f"Disconnected from {voiceChannel.channel}")```
````